# How to solve IntelliSense error in auto generated temporal table

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, intellisense, temporal-tables

I'm trying to use temporal tables in my SQL server db project in visual studio.

A sample table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sale Types] 
(
    [Id]         INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]       VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    SysStartTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    SysEndTime   DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime,SysEndTime),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Sale Types] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.[Sale Types History]));
```

My problem comes from errors being generated in these auto generated tables (`dbo.[Sale Types History]`)

> Error SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near Types

Comment: Probably something going wrong because of the spaces in the table names. Why not `SaleTypes` and `SaleTypesHistory`? that way you won't have to quote them everywhere

Comment: That's going to be a fun day of refactoring and migrations. I think your right but I'm surprised that they don't handle the common `[table name]`  syntax.

Comment: I've repro-ed by pasting your code into SSDT and building the project and getting the same error on build and validated that it goes away with `HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.[SaleTypesHistory]` so does just look like a bug with spaces

Comment: Maybe in SSDT - create a table definition for `Sale Types History` table yourself so it doesn't try and autocreate a definition with incorrect syntax